# Class inheritance type checking after pickling in Python

Tags: python, types, pickle, python-2.x, dill

Is there a sure-fire way to check that the class of an object is a sub-class of the desired super?

For Example, in a migration script that I'm writing, I have to convert objects of a given type to dictionaries in a given manner to ensure two-way compatability of the data.

This is best summed up like so:

- Serializable

  - User
  - Status
  - Issue

    - Test
    - Set
  - Step
  - Cycle

However, when I'm recursively checking objects after depickling, I receive a Test object that yields the following results:

Testing data object type:

```
type(data)
```

> {type}< class'__main.Test' >

Testing Class type:

```
type(Test())
```

> {type}< class'__main.Test' >

Testing object type against class type:

```
type(Test()) == type(data)
```

> {bool}False

Testing if object isinstance() of Class:

```
isinstance(data, Test)
```

> {bool}False

Testing if Class isinstance() of Super Class:

```
isinstance(Test(), Serializable)
```

> {bool}True

Testing isinstance() of Super Class::

```
isinstance(data, Serializable)
```

> {bool}False

Interestingly, it doesn't appear to have any such problem prior to pickling as it handles the creation of dictionary and integrity hash just fine.
This only crops up with depickled objects in both Pickle and Dill.

For Context, here's the code in it's native environment - the DataCache object that is pickled:

```
class DataCache(object):
    _hash=""
    _data = None

    @staticmethod
    def genHash(data):
        dataDict = DataCache.dictify(data)
        datahash = json.dumps(dataDict, sort_keys=True)
        return hashlib.sha256(datahash).digest()

    @staticmethod
    def dictify(data):
        if isinstance(data,list):
            datahash = []
            for item in data:
                datahash.append(DataCache.dictify(item))
        elif isinstance(data,(dict, collections.OrderedDict)):
            datahash = collections.OrderedDict()
            for key,value in datahash.iteritems():
                datahash[key]= DataCache.dictify(value)
        elif isinstance(data, Serializable):
            datahash = data.toDict()
        else:
            datahash = data
        return datahash

    def __init__(self, restoreDict = {}):
        if restoreDict:
            self.__dict__.update(restoreDict)

    def __getinitargs__(self):
        return (self.__dict__)

    def set(self, data):
        self._hash = DataCache.genHash(data)
        self._data = data

    def verify(self):
        dataHash = DataCache.genHash(self._data)
        return (self._hash == dataHash)

    def get(self):
        return self._data
```

Finally, I know there's arguments for using JSON for readability in storage, I needed Pickle's ability to convert straight to and from Objects without specifying the object type myself. (thanks to the nesting, it's not really feasible)

Am I going mad here or does pickling do something to the class definitions?

**EDIT:**

Minimal Implementation:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import requests
from aenum import Enum
import json  # _tricks
import base64
import argparse
import os
import sys
import datetime
import dill
import hashlib
import collections


class Serializable(object):
    def __init__(self, initDict={}):
        if initDict:
            self.__dict__.update(initDict)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.sortSelf())

    def sortSelf(self):
        return collections.OrderedDict(sorted(self.__dict__.items()))

    def toDict(self):
        return self.__dict__

    def fromDict(self, dict):
        # Not using __dict__.update(...) to avoid polluting objects with the excess data
        varMap = self.__dict__
        if dict and varMap:
            for key in varMap:
                if (key in dict):
                    varMap[key] = dict[key]
            self.__dict__.update(varMap)
            return self
        return None


class Issue(Serializable):
    def __init__(self, initDict={}):
        self.id = 0
        self.key = ""
        self.fields = {}
        if initDict:
            self.__dict__.update(initDict)
        Serializable.__init__(self)

    def fieldToDict(self, obj, key, type):
        if key in obj:
            result = obj[key]
        else:
            return None
        if result is None:
            return None
        if isinstance(result, type):
            return result.toDict()
        return result

    def fromDict(self, jsonDict):
        super(Issue, self).fromDict(jsonDict)
        self.fields["issuetype"] = IssueType().fromDict(self.fields["issuetype"])
        self.fields["assignee"] = User().fromDict(self.fields["assignee"])
        self.fields["creator"] = User().fromDict(self.fields["creator"])
        self.fields["reporter"] = User().fromDict(self.fields["reporter"])
        return self

    def toDict(self):
        result = super(Issue, self).toDict()
        blankKeys = []
        for fieldName, fieldValue in self.fields.iteritems():
            if fieldValue is None:
                blankKeys.append(fieldName)
        if blankKeys:
            for key in blankKeys:
                self.fields.pop(key, None)
        result["fields"]["issuetype"] = self.fieldToDict(result["fields"], "issuetype", IssueType)
        result["fields"]["creator"] = self.fieldToDict(result["fields"], "creator", User)
        result["fields"]["reporter"] = self.fieldToDict(result["fields"], "reporter", User)
        result["fields"]["assignee"] = self.fieldToDict(result["fields"], "assignee", User)
        return result


class IssueType(Serializable):
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = 0
        self.name = ""

    def toDict(self):
        return {"id": str(self.id)}


class Project(Serializable):
    def __init__(self):
        Serializable.__init__(self)
        self.id = 0
        self.name = ""
        self.key = ""


class Cycle(Serializable):
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = 0
        self.name = ""
        self.totalExecutions = 0
        self.endDate = ""
        self.description = ""
        self.totalExecuted = 0
        self.started = ""
        self.versionName = ""
        self.projectKey = ""
        self.versionId = 0
        self.environment = ""
        self.totalCycleExecutions = 0
        self.build = ""
        self.ended = ""
        self.name = ""
        self.modifiedBy = ""
        self.projectId = 0
        self.startDate = ""
        self.executionSummaries = {'executionSummary': []}


class Step(Serializable):
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = ""
        self.orderId = 0
        self.step = ""
        self.data = ""
        self.result = ""
        self.attachmentsMap = {}

    def toDict(self):
        dict = {}
        dict["step"] = self.step
        dict["data"] = self.data
        dict["result"] = self.result
        dict["attachments"] = []
        return dict


class Status(Serializable):
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = 0
        self.name = ""
        self.description = ""
        self.isFinal = True
        self.color = ""
        self.isNative = True
        self.statusCount = 0
        self.statusPercent = 0.0


class User(Serializable):
    def __init__(self):
        self.displayName = ""
        self.name = ""
        self.emailAddress = ""
        self.key = ""
        self.active = False
        self.timeZone = ""


class Execution(Serializable):
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = 0
        self.orderId = 0
        self.cycleId = -1
        self.cycleName = ""
        self.issueId = 0
        self.issueKey = 0
        self.projectKey = ""
        self.comment = ""
        self.versionId = 0,
        self.versionName = "",
        self.executedOn = ""
        self.creationDate = ""
        self.executedByUserName = ""
        self.assigneeUserName = ""
        self.status = {}
        self.executionStatus = ""

    def fromDict(self, jsonDict):
        super(Execution, self).fromDict(jsonDict)
        self.status = Status().fromDict(self.status)
        # This is already listed as Execution Status, need to associate and convert!
        return self

    def toDict(self):
        result = super(Execution, self).toDict()
        result['status'] = result['status'].toDict()
        return result


class ExecutionContainer(Serializable):
    def __init__(self):
        self.executions = []

    def fromDict(self, jsonDict):
        super(ExecutionContainer, self).fromDict(jsonDict)
        self.executions = []
        for executionDict in jsonDict["executions"]:
            self.executions.append(Execution().fromDict(executionDict))
        return self


class Test(Issue):
    def __init__(self, initDict={}):
        if initDict:
            self.__dict__.update(initDict)
        Issue.__init__(self)

    def toDict(self):
        result = super(Test, self).toDict()
        stepField = "CustomField_0001"
        if result["fields"][stepField]:
            steps = []
            for step in result["fields"][stepField]["steps"]:
                steps.append(step.toDict())
            result["fields"][stepField] = steps
        return result

    def fromDict(self, jsonDict):
        super(Test, self).fromDict(jsonDict)
        stepField = "CustomField_0001"
        steps = []
        if stepField in self.fields:
            for step in self.fields[stepField]["steps"]:
                steps.append(Step().fromDict(step))
        self.fields[stepField] = {"steps": steps}
        return self


class Set(Issue):
    def __init__(self, initDict={}):
        self.__dict__.update(initDict)
        Issue.__init__(self)


class DataCache(object):
    _hash = ""
    _data = None

    @staticmethod
    def genHash(data):
        dataDict = DataCache.dictify(data)
        datahash = json.dumps(dataDict, sort_keys=True)
        return hashlib.sha256(datahash).digest()

    @staticmethod
    def dictify(data):
        if isinstance(data, list):
            datahash = []
            for item in data:
                datahash.append(DataCache.dictify(item))
        elif isinstance(data, (dict, collections.OrderedDict)):
            datahash = collections.OrderedDict()
            for key, value in datahash.iteritems():
                datahash[key] = DataCache.dictify(value)
        elif isinstance(data, Serializable):
            datahash = data.toDict()
        else:
            datahash = data
        return datahash

    def __init__(self, restoreDict={}):
        if restoreDict:
            self.__dict__.update(restoreDict)

    def __getinitargs__(self):
        return (self.__dict__)

    def set(self, data):
        self._hash = DataCache.genHash(data)
        self._data = data

    def verify(self):
        dataHash = DataCache.genHash(self._data)
        return (self._hash == dataHash)

    def get(self):
        return self._data

def saveCache(name, projectKey, object):
    filePath = "migration_caches/{projectKey}".format(projectKey=projectKey)

    if not os.path.exists(path=filePath):
        os.makedirs(filePath)
    cache = DataCache()
    cache.set(object)
    targetFile = open("{path}/{name}".format(name=name, path=filePath), 'wb')
    dill.dump(obj=cache, file=targetFile)
    targetFile.close()


def loadCache(name, projectKey):
    filePath = "migration_caches/{projectKey}/{name}".format(name=name, projectKey=projectKey)
    result = False
    try:
        targetFile = open(filePath, 'rb')
        try:
            cache = dill.load(targetFile)
            if isinstance(cache, DataCache):
                if cache.verify():
                    result = cache.get()
        except EOFError:
            #            except BaseException:
            print ("Failed to load cache from file: {filePath}\n".format(filePath=filePath))
    except IOError:
        ("Failed to load cache file at: {filePath}\n".format(filePath=filePath))
    targetFile.close()
    return result


testIssue = Test().fromDict({"id": 1000,
                             "key": "TEST",
                             "fields": {
                                "issuetype": {
                                    "id": 1,
                                    "name": "TestIssue"
                                },
                                "assignee": "Minothor",
                                "reporter": "Minothor",
                                "creator": "Minothor",
                             }
                             })
saveCache("Test", "TestProj", testIssue)
result = loadCache("Test", "TestProj")
```

**EDIT 2**

The script in it's current form, now seems to work correctly with vanilla Pickle, (initially switched to Dill due to a similar issue, which was solved by the switch).

However, if you are here with this issue and require Dill's features, then as Mike noted in the comments - it's possible to change the settings in `dill.settings` to have Dill behave pickle referenced items only with `joblib` mode, effectively mirroring pickle's standard pickling behaviour.

Comment: Which version of python are you using? (I cannot get the outputs you are getting)
And have you considered placing your classes into a separate module and importing them from there? Pickling/unpickling instances of classes from __main__ is usually not a good idea.

Comment: I'm Developing for Python 2.4 (lowest server version, unfortunately something I have no control over) but my local machine is running python2.7.14


I'll look into separating out the classes, but considering it was meant to be a migration script for non-developers

(i.e. a script, sample config file and a jargon-free work doc)

I'd perfer to explore other options first if I can.

Comment: A [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be nice. Side note: Pickle isn't a good/usable format for long term storage. I wouldn't use it for anything more than caching data that can be restored when loading fails or as intermediate format in ”live” communications.

Comment: I'm the `dill` author.  You may have issues with serialization across versions of python.  A pickle created in python 2.4 is not guaranteed to be usable in python 2.7.  Many objects pickle cross-version, as long as you choose the same pickle protocol, however some don't.

Comment: I'd recommend (1) giving a minimal example that people can run, (2) trying one of the pickling variants in `dill.settings`, and (3) trying `klepto`, which allows easy database-like encoding with `dill`, `JSON`, `HDF`, and other formats.

Comment: @BlackJack Added the MCV to the end, and a short-term cache is exactly the usage in this case, since I'm pulling in about 30+GB of data per server during this migration, I'm caching each main block of data (Issues, Steps, Cycles and Executions) for each project locally so that I can resume cleanly from network dropouts or my org's irritating overnight shut-down policy. The main issue is guaranteeing against data loss or corrupted pickles (something I experienced thanks to the aforementioned shutdown), hence the hash verification.

Comment: @MikeMcKerns Don't worry, the pickle will only ever be created and used in the same environment, as I mentioned in my response to BlackJack, it's purpose is just to server as a quick Object->File->Object cache in case of drop-outs or problems in script execution.
Klepto sounds interesting, my main issue at the moment seems to be that the de-pickled classes seem to differ from the pre-prickled ones, nor recognise that they are a compatible type. I'm trying experiments on the data such as "type(data)()" which compains that it needs an instance of the supertype (asking for the correct one too)

Comment: How are you running your script?  It looks like it might be a `-m` issue…

Comment: @DavisHerring literally just "python script.py"

More accurately: "python script.py -resume" since the cache loading behaviour is only triggered by that flag. (the only changes being that it loads the caches into the appropate vars and sets a contuing point before lauching the digest method in my original script, the behaviour is replicated in the MCV included above though)

Comment: @Minothor: yes, pre-pickled classes can be different than post-pickled classes.  There's a few utilities in `dill` that allows you to check that pretty easily, primary of which is `dill.pickles`.  For `class Foo(object): pass`, you get `dill.pickles(Foo, exact=True, safe=True)` to be `False`, which means the class is not the same as the original.

Comment: The MCV fails with `dill` but works with `pickle` for me. (You can loose some of the unused `import`s btw.)

Comment: Again, you might want to check out some of the pickle variants in `dill.settings` -- there are at least three variants that cover the range between "aggressive" (pickle everything, the default), to pickle only referenced items (e.g. `joblib` pickling), to pickle by reference (e.g. the way `pickle` does it).

Comment: @MikeMcKerns funnily enough, my main script is now seeming to work with pickle (I initially switched to Dill due to an ealier issue not mentioned here, so it would appear that in trying to resolve this, the earlier issue with Pickle is now resolved...)

I'm not really sure what to say to that..

Cheers for your help though, this is a heavy weight off my mind.

Comment: @BlackJack Cheers for pointing that out, I initially switched from Pickle due to a similar issue with serialization, to this, but it would appear that some of the changes I made when trying to resolve this issue, have resolved that earlier one(I wish I knew which ones)
Thanks for the help though, I may be able to get this migration back on track now!